# Is (2,0,1) an eigenvector of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, linear-transformations

Let A = $ \begin{pmatrix}   5 &  1 & 2 \\ 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 4   \end{pmatrix}  $

(**)   $ A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\1  \end{pmatrix}  =  \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ -3  \end{pmatrix}$, $ \quad $ $ A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\0  \end{pmatrix}  =  \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 6 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}$, $ \quad $ $ A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\1  \end{pmatrix}  =  \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ -6 \\ 6  \end{pmatrix}$, $ \quad   \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\0  \end{pmatrix}  +  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}$

Which of the following is true?

(1) $ (2,0,1) $ is an eigenvector associated to 3

(2)  $ (2,0,1) $ is an eigenvector associated to 6

(3)  $ (2,0,1) $ is not an eigenvector of A

I found that **only (2) is true** by using the characteristic polynomial, but how do I prove that (2) is true using (**), as intended by the question?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have
$$
A\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}
=
A\left(\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\0  \end{pmatrix}  +  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}\right)=  \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 6 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ -6 \\ 6  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 0 \\ 6  \end{pmatrix}=6\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are two eigenvectors of a matrix $M$ with respect to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, i.e. $Mv_1=\lambda v_1$ and $Mv_2=\lambda v_2$, then *any linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$, is also an eigenvector of $M$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$*, since $M(av_1+bv_2)=aMv_1+bMv_2=a\lambda v_1+b\lambda v_2=\lambda(av_1+bv_2)$.

Now for $v_1=\pmatrix{1\\1\\0}$ and $v_2=\pmatrix{1\\-1\\1}$, we have $Av_1=6v_1$ and $Av_2=6v_2$. Hence $v_1$ and $v_2$ are eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $6$. Hence $v_1+v_2=\pmatrix{2\\0\\1}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $6$.

Comment: So, $ (1,1,0), (1,-1,1) $ would be the eigenvectors associated with eigenvalue 6? But, (1,0,-1) is associated to 3 right?

Comment: Yep, $(1,0,-1)$ is associated to eigenvalue $3$, but that information is not quite useful in this problem